# cloning jquery mobile form elements

Tags: jquery, mobile, clone, listeners

I created a div with id=template which wraps around some html code that I want to repeat when user clicks a button.  Jquery mobile automatically adds some special formating to this code (such as mouse-over and on-click css colors).  The clone works OK, however when I clone the code, the formating is lost. Is there a way to clone with jquery mobile formating.

```
  <!-- I think that these are required links... -->
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquerymobile.com/wp-content/themes/jquery-mobile/js/lib/modernizr-1.5.min.js"> </script>

</script>
    <script>
    $('.addPart').click(function() {    
        var myClone = $('#template').clone();        
        myClone.prependTo("#placeholder");  
        return false;
        });   
    </script>

        <div id='template'> 
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <input type="radio" data-theme="a" name="ACFG" id="radio-choice-1" value="C" checked="checked" /><label for="radio-choice-1">One</label>
        <input type="radio" data-theme="a" name="ACFG" id="radio-choice-2" value="T"  /><label for="radio-choice-2">Two</label>
        <input type="radio" data-theme="a" name="ACFG" id="radio-choice-3" value="P"  /><label for="radio-choice-3">Three</label>
        </fieldset>
        </div> 
        </div>

    <div id='placeholder'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing closing quotes

```
myClone.prependTo("#placeholder);
```

Works now: 
http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/6YtcH/

Comment: thanks, but thats not it. It fell off while I was simplifying code for the post. Without the quote the javascript would have failed.

Comment: Why were you simplifying the code for your post? Odds are your bug was in the code you cut off during your simplification

Comment: no one would appreciate if i posted 5 pages of javascript manipulation.  My example cuts to the core of my problem. I will add the jquery library references.  If you add these hopefully the issue will be apparent.  Issue is that Jquery mobile styling is not added when on cloned copies.

Comment: BTW jsfiddle site looks AMAzing!